# “invalid Appium session” when running LeanFT with Mobile Center

Tags: mobile, leanft, microfocus-mobile-center

I've tried to run Mobile test from LeanFT using Mobile Center.
However, when starting the test, getting "Invalid Appium Session" exception. Is there any way to overcome it?

Answer (score 2):

After investigation, this is an issue by LeanFT job session management, however you can have a workaround at MC side to overcome the “invalid Appium session” issue.

Please go to
/connector/jetty/webapps/hp4m-connector/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties
Change below value
appium.timeouts.sendAndReceive.minimumInSeconds=30000

Restart MC service and LeanFT runtime engine, then rerun your test, it would work fine.

If you plug your device directly to MC server (embedded connector), the file path should be
/server/jetty/webapps/hp4m-connector/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties